# Duplicate bindings error when trying to go to next row in DB

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I am new to this whole binding thing but basically when i press next button on my form it is meant to scroll through my database displaying each row but the code i will supply below is just a temp as i want to make sure it all works before adding more code to it.

When i load the section i have it so it preloads the first row into my form so when you press next it will bring you to row 2 and next again will bring you to row 3 etc but when i hit next to go to row 3 from row 2 i receive the error: This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.

Code:

```vb
Private Sub click()
    sql = "Select * from tbl"
    Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, dbcon)

            dbcon.Open()

            dtSample = New DataTable
            dtSample.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

        End Using
    End Using

    ' initialize BS from DT
    bsSample = New BindingSource(dtSample, Nothing)

    TxtCI.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSample, "CustomerID")
End Sub
```

Next button:

```vb
Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click
    click()
    DataBindings.Clear()
    bsSample.MoveNext()

    BtnNext.Enabled = (bsSample.Count - 1 > bsSample.Position)
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `nClick` from BtnNext_Click - there is no need to requery or rebind.  Also remove `DataBindings.Clear()`.  The code in nclick is something you want to happen only once, like in a form load.  It creates ONE DT and associates the BS with it.  Both are infinitely reusable.

Comment: See i had nclick() cause its in a function as i call it so now since i removed the nclick() it get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where - on what object/line?  (its not a function, it is a method).  That code needs to run but only once *like in a form load*

Comment: The error occurs on the `bsSample.MoveNext()` line its pointing here. I learn something new everyday haha i code python and so when i see lets say nclick() that to me is a function but guess its called a method on here:D So i need to call nclick on formload perhaps?

Comment: Is this portion a dialog?  That DT has many, many uses in the other code you have.  But for this, yes just move the entire block to form load so it is created once and only once

Comment: I added the line: nclick() just to the formload and works now?:D i removed it like you said from the next button and i just put it in that and works? So i guess i am happy with that:)

Comment: The general term for `nclick` in NET is a method.  In VB parlance that is a `Sub` because it returns nothing, in C# it would be called a void method.

Comment: Well i do have to say, you saved me again here and in the process you are teaching me new ways and new terms (The real terms) and i say i will have some questions on this in my end of year exam and knowing my luck it will ask what it means and i now have some understanding of the terms:) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code block:

```
Private Sub nclick()
    sql = "Select * from tblcustomer"
    Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, dbcon)

            dbcon.Open()

            dtSample = New DataTable
            dtSample.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    ' initialize BS from DT
    bsSample = New BindingSource(dtSample, Nothing)
    TxtCI.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSample, "CustomerID")
    TxtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSample, "Title")
    ChkSales.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bsSample, "SalesCustomer")
End Sub
```

...needs to run once, but *only* once.  Move the whole lot of it to the form load.  Then:

```
Private Sub BtnNext_Click...
    bsSample.MoveNext()

    BtnNext.Enabled = (bsSample.Count - 1 > bsSample.Position)
End Sub
```

I am not sure if this is a Find dialog or what, but it should be noted that the DataTable for all customers can have application-wide uses - such as checking if customer #30 exists before trying to delete them.

Comment: Last issue which i just have is when i hit my button to go to end of row it works and when i hit previous a few times the btn next is blanked out (as if i am at end of row). Code: `Private Sub BtnSEnd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSEnd.Click
        bsSample.MoveLast()
    End Sub`

Comment: When you get to the end (`bsSample.Count - 1 > bsSample.Position`) the button is disabled as per the org question.  Its not really needed: nothing bad happens when you try to MoveNext past the end of the set.  If you want to Enable them that way you will have to add that code to the other buttons as well.  That way when you get to the end, it is disabled, when you MovePrev it gets turned back on.  You'll need a line like that for all the buttons

Comment: Ahh ok i understand, solved it there with some if statements! Thanks for the help:)

Comment: What would be the code for locking the previous button. I used: `BtnStart.Enabled = (bsSample.Count - 1 < bsSample.Position)` to turn it off when at the start and tried using that for the previous button but when i press previous button and it not being the last record it still disables? Possibly the code, what you think Plutonix?

Comment: the part in the `()` is an expression equating to T or F.  You want Prev to be off when the position is zero so: `btnPrev.Enabled = (bs.Postion > 0)`  you will need that in the other click events too so it it gets turned on when you move away from 0

Comment: How do i go about using my if statement on my business name = blanked when going next on the buttons using this whole bindings? I tried but cant figure out. My orignal code is: ` Dim word
        word = ds.Tables("tblcustomer").Rows(0).Item(15)
        If IsDBNull(word) Then
            TxtBName.Text = "No Business Name"
        Else
            TxtBName.Text = ds.Tables("tblcustomer").Rows(0).Item(15)
        End If`

Comment: **Dont** poke text into these controls - that is an edit and will change the name to `No Business Name` !  You should carefully read the text for the other answer: if you do SELECT * you have NO CONTROL over the order of the columns, so fiddling with `...Item(15)` kind of only works by accident.  When there is nothing, I'd just leave it blank.  You dont have to be very smart to know `""` means no name was given.  Can they update records from this thing?

Comment: No basically the aim of this program is for company owners to log their customers details such as add new client, delete client search for client same with orders and then a simple email section but i completed the delete customer and done the add customer, now its just getting this search up and as for orders itl be a simple copy paste job while changing few things!:) So as for can they update things? Nah, they click search and can only browse for customers as far as i am aware:)

Comment: No, these are LIVE CONTROLS which will EDIT THE DATA when they type stuff into them.  The previous answer in this series showed how to make it read only.  There is a way to show "(None)" or whatever for missing data, but trust me, an IFomatProvider just for that is silly and too much work.  You have probably outpaced the rest of the class just by learning about bindingsources